# No executable found matching command "dotnet-test-xunit"

Tags: .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I am trying to run a xunit test project. I've followed the below steps to do that so, but however I've been getting **"No executable found matching command dotnet-test-xunit"** error.

**Steps:**
1. Created a folder named **"Tests"** in the local drive.
2. Keeping the "Tests" folder as current directory in the command line, I ran the following commands:
**a) dotnet new --type xunittest

b) dotnet restore

c) dotnet test**
3. Finally, while executing the **"dotnet test"** command, I got "dotnet-test-xunit" not found.

My .NET(dotnet) version: **1.0.0-preview2-003131**

Also, when I searched for the "dotnet-test-xunit" package in the nuget repository (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=dotnet-test-xunit), it is not found.

Can anyone guide me through this ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

The [dotnet-test-xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-test-xunit) package has been unlisted.

.NET Core projects that are project.json-based are no longer supported (preview2 and earlier versions).

Newer versions of .NET Core use the [xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/) package.